# How to extract multiple nested attributes from all items in a list of dicts?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of objects and I need to pull out multiple attributes from the items in the list so that the result is a list of only those attributes and none of the others. Here's what my original data looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Error while parsing document: files/file1.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "invocation": {
      "module_args": {
        "path": "files/file1.xml"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Error while parsing document: files/file2.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "invocation": {
      "module_args": {
        "path": "files/file2.xml"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need to map the `msg` and `invocation.module_args.path` attributes into new objects. The resulting list should look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "msg": "Error while parsing document: files/file1.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "path": "files/file1.xml"
  },
  {
    "msg": "Error while parsing document: files/file2.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "path": "files/file2.xml"
  }
]
```

If I can possibly define new attribute names that would be preferred, but it's lower priority:

```json
[
  {
    "error": "Error while parsing document: files/file1.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "file": "files/file1.xml"
  },
  {
    "error": "Error while parsing document: files/file2.xml (Opening and ending tag mismatch)",
    "file": "files/file2.xml"
  }
]
```

I can do this by creating an additional task file and looping over it, creating each dict object and updating the list but I'd rather just use a single task and/or Jinja2 filter if possible to simplify things.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) data

```yaml
    l1:
      - failed: true
        invocation:
          module_args: {path: files/file1.xml}
        msg: 'Error: files/file1.xml'
      - failed: true
        invocation:
          module_args: {path: files/file2.xml}
        msg: 'Error: files/file2.xml'
```

Use *json_query*. For example,

```yaml
  err: "{{ l1|json_query('[].{error: msg,
                              file: invocation.module_args.path}') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  err:
  - error: 'Error: files/file1.xml'
    file: files/file1.xml
  - error: 'Error: files/file2.xml'
    file: files/file2.xml
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    l1:
      - failed: true
        invocation:
          module_args: {path: files/file1.xml}
        msg: 'Error: files/file1.xml'
      - failed: true
        invocation:
          module_args: {path: files/file2.xml}
        msg: 'Error: files/file2.xml'

    err: "{{ l1|json_query('[].{error: msg,
                                file: invocation.module_args.path}') }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: err
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks!